# ERROR in undefined is not iterable! @ multi main

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

After updating some of the packages, my compilation fails. And the error doesn't seems to be very helpful.

I have no clues where the error is. Already tried removing a lot of things, and the errors persists.

I've pushed the project with the issue here: https://github.com/KadoBOT/reaxor/tree/need-validation

The error appears in two places, in the first line after I `npm start` and in the last line after the bundle finishes

```
(...)
[0] multi main 64 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[1] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 2.67 kB {0} [built]
[2] ./~/url/url.js 22.3 kB {0} [built]
(...)
```

And:

```
(...)
ERROR in undefined is not iterable!
 @ multi main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Anyone experienced the same problem after upgrading packages? How do I solve this, since there is no hint, where the issue is?

Comment: This just happened to me as well today. Not sure what is wrong just yet.

Comment: Well, glad that is not happening only with me. Let's wait till this issue is gone then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saw this tweet from babel: https://twitter.com/babeljs/status/727301512041512961

Might help you with your problem? I have a team member running into the same issue just now and we are trying that out...

Comment: Worked. Thanks, was getting nuts :D